# How to add arrays of type object[] to the ArrayList<object[]>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have 20 arrays which I would like to add them to `ArrayList<object[]>` to iterate through and work with. How can I add them to the `ArrayList<object[]>`?

```
[1301 - PB, 2017-02-20 19:43:42.0, 2017-02-20 19:48:59.0, 0.0900, 0, 0.09, 0.09, 0.66],
 [1302 - PB3, 2017-02-20 20:26:47.0, 2017-02-20 20:32:17.0, 0.0900, 0.09, 0.18, 0.09, 0.66],
 [1303 - PB, 2017-02-20 20:33:58.0, 2017-02-20 20:42:05.0, 0.1400, 0.18, 0.32, 0.14, 0.66],
 [1304 - PB, 2017-02-20 20:47:48.0, 2017-02-20 20:53:59.0, 0.1000, 0.32, 0.42, 0.09999999999999998, 0.66]
```

**Code**

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object[]> x = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object[] array = { "1303 - PB300", "2017-02-20 19:43:42.0", "2017-02-20 19:48:59.0", 0.0900, 0, 0.09, 0.09,
            0.66 };
    x.add(array);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried invoking the `add()` method?

Comment: Your code already contains `list.add(array1);`. This should allow you to add `array1` to `list` (assuming that array is properly created). Is there any problem with your code?

Comment: @LoganKulinski It's in the code. I really think he is getting compilation errors in the array1 declaration line (if this is the real code).

Comment: Adding is not the problem here. The problem is that your code is invalid Java code. What is `1303 - PB300` supposed to be? If it's supposed to be a string, then it should be `"1303 - PB300"`. Same for the rest of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer here: avoid treating data as "low level" strings / arrays.

I guess that

```
[1301 - PB, 2017-02-20 19:43:42.0, 2017-02-20 19:48:59.0, 0.0900, 0, 0.09, 0.09, 0.66]
```

represents some piece of data that actually belongs together. So instead of simply pushing these data points into an array; why don't you create a special class to hold those objects? And while doing so, you also give the "columns" a name; and a meaning; and means for validation.

And then, instead of dealing with `List<Object[]>` - then you just use a `List<YourDataClass>`.

And adding really goes like:

```
list.add(newMember);
```

that's it.

Or maybe:

```
list = Arrays.asList(member1, member2, member3);
```

Very much like the code you provided ... and that compiles and runs fine.

Final note: even when you want to keep that list of list approach; why do you want to use arrays here? Just use `List<List<SomeType>>` instead of mixing arrays and lists.